# Groovy syntax with Gradle: project

Tags: gradle, groovy

I'm looking at a Gradle file where I see

```
implementation project(path: ':module_1')
```

or

```
implementation project(':module_2')
```

I expect they are the same since `project` is defined as `Project project(String path)`. Am I wrong? If not, how Groovy is able to achieve the syntax above (omitting the `path` parameter)?

Thanks,
Lorenzo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st there's no way of writing

```
implementation project(path ':module_1')
```

Here the `:` is missing:

```
implementation project(path:':module_1')
```

Now this is a valid groovy syntax and means, that here the `Map` literal (with ommitted brackets) is passed in.
In bad'ol java you would have to write:

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put( "path", ":module_1" );
implementation( project( map ) );
```

or alternatively in Groovy:

```
implementation project( [ path:':module_1' ] )
```

The `project(String)` and `project(Map)` methods seem to be identical, when the map contains the `path` pair only.

See [the API-docs section](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.DependencyHandler.html#N17306) for further details.

Comment: Ah, __good ol' java__, when you could just read the code and know what everything was without having to refer to the API-docs, and blogs on syntactic sugar alternatives.